# Material with full transmission still casts dark shadows, how do I avoid that? (Cycles render)

Tags: materials, transparency, shadows

(I'm using cycles render)

I'm trying to create the look of 'essential oil' blobs on a surface.
I want the oil to look very clear, only slightly colored.

It looks how I want when the blobs are not on a surface (ignore the gackground image, it's only to see how transparent and clear the material is):

[image]

But when I place a plane under the blobs, it looks like this:
[image]

The material is still clear, however it is casting a dark shadow on the plane, making it look like the oil blobs are dark.
I could simply disable ray visibility for shadows in the oil blobs, but I would rather have realistic shadows, but a clear transparent object like this shouldn't cast such a dark shadow.

Here are the settings from my 'oil' material:
[image]

What settings should I change (in the material itself or in the render settings) to make the shadows not appear as dark, in the most realistic way possible?

Comment: are you using EEVEE or Cycles?  They handle transparency very differently from each other.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that, will update the question. I'm using cycles.

Comment: This has to do with caustics. See the manual on how to fix or avoid such.

Comment: I tried looking into it in the blender manual but I only found information about noise caused by caustics, not the darkness of the shadow.

Comment: did you try to use a mix shader with transparent? The pros will kill me, but might work....

Comment: I didn't try mix shader yet. I think that would work, but was hoping for a more "physically accurate" option. I will try it anyway, thanks.

Comment: at least ...now they WILL kill me....animation and design is 99.99999% fake. ;) it just has to "look" realistic (if this is wanted). At least we are just moving pixels around...and try that it looks amazing ;)

Comment: Yes, I agree. I tried it and it doesn't seem to affect how dark it looks. I tried it on an object with no transmission and it worked, I could tweak the darkness of the shadow, but on objects with full transmission it doesn't seem to make a difference. I'm sure Zargul is right, it has to do with caustics, but I can't find any way to tweak caustic settings (only turn on or off in the render properties tab).